# Comparing and merging two strings in an XML file using Java

Tags: java, xml, merge, compare

I have two xml files which are stored as strings. I want to compare a particular string in each xml file and if those strings match, I need to merge them as a single XML file in Java:

`file1.xml:`

```
<docs>
  <doc>
    <id>102</id>
    <name>Samsung</name>
    <brand>S3</brand>
  </doc> 

</docs>
```

`file2.xml :`

```
<docs>
  <doc>
    <id>102</id>
    <stock>10</stock>
  </doc> 
</docs>
```

I want to compare the IDs (i.e 102) in the 2 XML files using Java and if it matches, then I want the following output in a single XML file

`output.xml:`

```
<docs>
  <doc>
    <id>102</id>
    <name>Samsung</name>
    <brand>S3</brand>
    <stock>10</stock>
  </doc>
</docs>
```

Please provide me a exact code for this as I am very new to this topic. If possible try to give me an answer without using the loop statment

Comment: I dono where to start itself..i tried many things but nothing working out so which made me to start it from the scratch

Comment: How did you read XML file? Did you try DOM parser (http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/javax.xml.parsers/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java.html)

Comment: the prob is, shld not use DOM parser.need to get the output without DOM parser

Comment: But that is part of standard Java library. How will you read an XML otherwise? May be I can suggest some example if you are willing to use DOM parser.

Comment: As DOM cant handle huge XML files, ll be using SAX/StAX

Comment: Can you post some sample code which you are using?

Comment: Also update the question that you dont want to use DOM Parser. Provide as much info as you can so that others can help you.

Comment: ok..I also want to know whether can we put the entire XMl as strings and compare both the XML

Comment: Do you mean like this: `String xml2 = "<docs><doc><id>102</id><name>Samsung</name><brand>S3</brand></doc></docs>";`? Yes you can but what are you trying to achieve? I am still confused.

Comment: Yes,You are right. In this i want to compare ID's and if they are same then the output should be <docs>
  <doc>
    <id>102</id>
    <name>Samsung</name>
    <brand>S3</brand>
    <stock>10</stock>
  </doc>
</docs>

Comment: Why would you want to store XML in string form? What if XML is huge is size? IMO it is better to keep it in XML format.

Comment: Can you please check whether my solution works for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example which works as per your need. The `SAXHandler` is the handler class and it will collect all `Doc` objects after parsing of XML in `docsList`.

```
class SAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    List<Doc> docsList = new ArrayList<>();
    Doc doc = null;
    String content = null;

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName,
                             String qName, Attributes attributes)
            throws SAXException {

        switch(qName){
            //Create a new Doc object when the start tag is found
            case "doc":
                doc = new Doc();
                doc.id = attributes.getValue("id");
                doc.name = attributes.getValue("name");
                doc.brand = attributes.getValue("brand");
                doc.stock = attributes.getValue("stock");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
                           String qName) throws SAXException {
        switch(qName){
            case "doc":
                docsList.add(doc);
                break;
            case "id":
                doc.id = content;
                break;
            case "name":
                doc.name = content;
                break;
            case "brand":
                doc.brand = content;
                break;
            case "stock":
                doc.stock = content;
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        content = String.copyValueOf(ch, start, length).trim();
    }

}
```

The `Doc` is the class which will contain document objects.

```
class Doc {
    String id;
    String name;
    String brand;
    String stock;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Doc{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", brand='" + brand + '\'' +
                ", Stock='" + stock + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The main class is `XMLFileReadAndMergeUsingSAX` which will contain the above two classes as nested classes.

```
public class XMLFileReadAndMergeUsingSAX {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        SAXParser parser = SAXParserFactory.newInstance().newSAXParser();
        SAXHandler handler1 = new SAXHandler();
        SAXHandler handler2 = new SAXHandler();
        InputStream is1 = XMLFileReadAndMergeUsingSAX.class.getResourceAsStream("abc.xml");
        InputStream is2 = XMLFileReadAndMergeUsingSAX.class.getResourceAsStream("def.xml");
        parser.parse(is1, handler1);
        parser.parse(is2, handler2);
        List<Doc> finalList = new ArrayList<>();
        // Print first xml for verification
        for (Doc doc1 : handler1.docsList) {
            System.out.println(doc1);
        }
        // Print second xml for verification
        for (Doc doc1 : handler2.docsList) {
            System.out.println(doc1);
        }

        for (Doc doc1 : handler1.docsList) {
            for (Doc doc2 : handler2.docsList) {
                if(doc1.id.equals(doc2.id)) {
                    Doc newDoc = new Doc();
                    newDoc.id = doc1.id;
                    newDoc.name = (doc1.name != null) ? (doc1.name) : (doc2.name);
                    newDoc.brand= (doc1.brand != null) ? (doc1.brand) : (doc2.brand);
                    newDoc.stock = (doc1.stock != null) ? (doc1.stock) : (doc2.stock);
                    finalList.add(newDoc);
                }
            }
        }

        //Now print final xml.
        for(Doc doc : finalList) {
            System.out.println(doc);
        }

    }
}
```

I have tested it with two xml files which has the following content:
**abc.xml**

```
<docs>
    <doc>
        <id>102</id>
        <name>Samsung</name>
        <brand>S3</brand>
    </doc>
</docs>
```

And
**def.xml**

```
<docs>
    <doc>
        <id>102</id>
        <stock>10</stock>
    </doc>
</docs>
```

And the result of running the code is:

```
Doc{id='102', name='Samsung', brand='S3', Stock='null'}
Doc{id='102', name='null', brand='null', Stock='10'}
Doc{id='102', name='Samsung', brand='S3', Stock='10'}
```

If you want to try this without loop then you can try creating a map and inserting/updating the result. If you want to read about the basics then [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html) is a good reference.

If you want to keep your XML in String form may be you can get `InputStream` as:

```
String xml2 = "<docs><doc><id>102</id><name>Samsung</name><brand>S3</brand></doc></docs>";
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml1.getBytes("utf-8"));
```

I have not tried it but it should work.